# Javascript error in Mozilla but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript

```
 <div class="videoitem">
         <div class="videotitle">
          <h3><a style='cursor:pointer;' onclick="watch('XhJe5sPGTUM','XhJe5sPGTUM2');"  class="watchvideo">Bartos Cs. István ~ 2013. májusi nagy tanítás</a></h3>

        </div>
        <div id='XhJe5sPGTUM2' style='display:none; '>

       <iframe width="560" height="315" style=' overflow:hidden' ></iframe>

       </div>
```

This is the html of the script

```
<script>

function watch(a , b){   
   var ajaxobj = $.ajax(
         {
            url:"vidload.php",
            type:"POST",
            data:{"vid":a},
            dataType:"html"
         });

         ajaxobj.done(
         function(vissza) 
         {

            $("#"+ b).html(vissza);
            fadeSwitchElements(a, b); 

         });     

}; 

function fadeSwitchElements(id1, id2)
{
    var element1 = $('#' + id1);
    var element2 = $('#' + id2);

    if(element1.is(':visible'))
    {
        element1.css("display", "none");
        element2.css("display", "block");

    }
    else
    {
         element2.fadeToggle(500, function() {
            element1.fadeToggle(500);
        });   
    }    
}

</script>
```

This is what Mozilla says:

> TypeError: "XhJe5sPGTUM2" is not a function in line 1

I don't understand this... I have zero idea why this doesn't work in Mozilla.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that `watch` is in Firefox a function:
[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch)

Replace watch with something other. e.g. `my_watch`